# How to prevent vertical scrollbar flicker in CListCtrl after re-population of its items

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, clistctrl

My goal is to redraw `CListCtrl` in my MFC app at 1 second frequency to refresh its contents. I use the following pseudocode to do that:

```
//CListCtrl lstLog;

//Prevent redrawing
lstLog.SetRedraw(FALSE);

//Remove all items
lstLog.DeleteAllItems();

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    lstLog.InsertItem(i, str);
}

//Scroll to the bottom of the list
int scrollY = lstLog.GetItemCount() * nItemHeight;

//Allow back redrawing
lstLog.SetRedraw(TRUE);
lstLog.Scroll(CSize(0, scrollY));
```

This works well except that the vertical scrollbar seems to flicker, or quickly jump up and down, when I use this method.

Is there something that I can do to prevent that?

Comment: Does it help if you do the scroll before turning redraw back on?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: You know, if I do that, it creates a weird effect. On the first iteration it scrolls to the bottom, then on the next iteration it scrolls to the very top, and then repeats. I checked `scrollY` and that parameter doesn't seem to change.

Comment: Just the scrollbar does that or the list itself?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: The whole list along with the scrollbar...

Comment: What happens if you subtract the client height of the listview control from the scroll amount (you're technically scrolling too far down, although I would have expected the listview to clip the scroll but maybe it's doing something weird like wrapping around).

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I tried to do `scrollY = 10 * nIh;` instead and it didn't help the scrollbar flicker. Also tried it on Win 7 and 8.1.

Comment: If you can provide a MCVE I can have a play and see if I can work out what's causing it, I don't have any other ideas at the moment.

Comment: I might have one, is that perhaps called from another but the GUI thread?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: No, there's only one thread in the app. I call it from WM_TIMER message handler.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Is there a way I can upload a VS project here?

Comment: You're clearing items (ik no redrawing) and scrollbar position too (not affected by no redraw). Just do not use InsertItem(), for existing entries you have SetItem(). You won't change scrollbar position and it won't move (and redraw).

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Avoid unnecessarily updating the listbox. Not only will that waste time, but it will interfere with the user trying to select something from it. Try to only update those elements where it is necessary.
- Check out `LockWindowUpdate()`. Write an RAII helper that locks the listbox for the time of refilling. Make sure you check the result of the call and only reverse this in the dtor if the first call was successful, to not interfere with nested calls.

Comment: Ok: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/21/1735472.aspx  Not ok: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/22/1742084.aspx

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Yeah, I agree. It's not an appropriate use for `LockWindowUpdate`. In despite of that I did try it and it made the flicker way worse. With it now the whole list control seems to flicker.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: `"Avoid unnecessarily updating the listbox"` -- so you're saying that Windows Task Manager was coded wrong?

Comment: That's worth of an actual answer to the question, @Jonathan. However, `SetWindowRedraw()` is exactly what they're doing, and it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: What I meant was that you should avoid changing the content unless the content really needs to be changed. Also, if you structure this event-bases, an item that needs to change will change much faster, not after a delay of up to 1s.